# coordinating comparisons with lists inside lists lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

So I want to run comparisons between coordinance that are arranged like so"

```
def my_function(lista, listb):
    ....

lista = [  [ [x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y] ]  ]

listb = [  [x,y], [x,y], [x,y], [x,y]  ]

listc = []
```

I have been, in this case simply doing this to call my function:

```
index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for i in index:
    temp = my_function(lista[0][i], listb[i])
    listc.append(temp)
```

However I have gotten to the point where I am now adding multiple list sequences to lista and want to have list called for each sequence in listb.

like so:

```
for i in lista:
    for q in listb:
        for z in q:
            my_function(i,z)
```

However I'm not sure if this will work and even if it does it will be very slow. I was wondering if anyone knows a cleaner, more efficient way to do this?

Bare in mind, this is an generative program and any and all data is variable.

Thanks,

Comment: Any particular reason your `lista` has an unnecessary one-element list wrapping the whole thing?

Comment: What do you mean by comparison?

Comment: you can probably use some tools from itertools to do this, but the bottleneck might be in your function. vectorizing that function might be better.

Comment: user2357112, more will be added making it look like this[ [[1,2], [2,3] [3,4]], [[1,2] [3,4]] ] thats why there is that extra list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you are trying will be slow.  That you can be sure.

However, if your "my_function"  is  making something complicated with the itens, it will be the way to go - i.e., running one loop with all list items, and another loop with all the items on the other list. That is compelxity O(m X n) and will become the mreo slow as you have more items.

If, however, you just want to check which items in listb are in lista and have these in listc,
there are fast ways of doing it.

The most appropriate way would be working with `sets`: an unordered container in Python which can check if an element is contained within it much faster than ordinary lists, which require sequential search.

But if all you want is just compare elements in both lists, bfore spelling out how to do that with sets, it is important that you understand that lists and other sequence types in Python are directly comparable - no need for a special function to compare them, or to the comparison item by item:

```
>>> [1, 1] == [1, 1]
True
```

And the same holds true even for deep structures of lists within lists
(or dictionaries, tuples , sets and lists inside one another): Python
will recursively compare all the elements in a complex data structure
just using the `==` operator.

Now, back to sets:
the final answer to your problem might be just:
(that is just comparing two lists at once -  since your 
`lista` has several lists inside it, you will need an extra loop to 
pick each of those at a time to create the sets and the intersection -
but it will be just one loop for each of the list of coordinates
inside `lista` - not a loop for each item in there)

```
seta = set(tuple(item) for item in lista) 
setb = set(tuple(item) for item in listb)
listc = list(setb.intersection(seta))
```

Comment: The function has a conditional as well as several math operations. I don't know if this would work.

Comment: The function is basically a formula working with the coordinance in lista and listb then sending the solution to listc.

Comment: In that case, you have no option but doing the O(m X n) way you do. ven if the function would be rewritten to use a list/st comprehension instead of the 3 explicit `for` loops you would not have any gain in the complexity. If speed is an issue there, and if there are repeated coordinates, you could benefit from memoizing techniques, tough. Not so if the coordinates are floating point in a non-quantized space.